# Add a lookup field for a list in Sharepoint Client Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, client-object-model

This is what I've achieved do far:

```
var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInfo.Title = "New List";
listCreationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.CustomGrid;
List list = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
list.Update();
ctxt.ExecuteQuery();
Field parent = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
    @"<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='ParentContentType' 
    Required='FALSE' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE'
    List='" + list.TemplateFeatureId + @"'
    ShowField='Title' UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary='FALSE' 
    RelationshipDeleteBehavior='None' 
    StaticName='ParentContentType' Name='ParentContentType'/>",
    true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
```

But I am not able to set the **Get information from:** value for this lookup field.
Can anyone please suggest how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:-

```
public static void AddLookupField()
{
            string lookupSchema = @"<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='mylookup2' 
                                    Required='FALSE' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE'
                                    List='{70d6098c-6ba0-4e9e-b101-a60b88fc226a}' 
                                    ShowField='Title' UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary='FALSE' 
                                    RelationshipDeleteBehavior='None' 
                                    StaticName='mylookup' Name='mylookup2'/>";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint10");
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listtitle");
            FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;

            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(fields);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Field lookupField = fields.AddFieldAsXml(lookupSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
            lookupField.Update();

            clientContext.Load(lookupField);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


}
```

Comment: Hey thanks @sharique, my issue got resolved. I used the list's GUID and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: you are welcome @CodeKaro

Answer (score 0):

The "List" attribute of the <Field> element should specify the list from which you wish to get information.

It should be the internal name of a list on the site; the internal name is in the format of a URL fragment, such as "Lists/MyList".

Comment: Hi @thriggle, thanks for the response. I have seen at some places that "List='{E0D2646A-63BE-4010-ABC7-4A5E2B8EF0E7}'" has been added. What does that mean?

Comment: Hi @CodeKaro, you can use a list's GUID instead of the list's URL if you want to refer to a list somewhere in the same site collection but not necessarily in the same site. I believe you'll need {curly braces} around the GUID of the desired list.